# Hot and neutral terminals are switched in a outlet

Tags: wiring

I am wiring a 30A-125V locking plug for an industrial toaster, however the outlet in the wall has the neutral and hot terminals switched, can I swap the terminals in the plug?

Comment: You know they are switched how?

Comment: the plug I purchased will not fit into the outlet..it is correct plug

Comment: I have switched the terminals in the plug and now it fits into the outlet, I am wondering if this is bad wiring in the wall or an odd or old plug that will cause problems down the road

Comment: ...old outlet rather

Comment: Did you try using a multimeter to test the outlet? Or a [simple tester like this?](http://www.amazon.com/Klein-Tools-RT100-Receptacle-Tester/dp/B005GYBFA4/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1452368601&sr=8-4&keywords=outlet+tester)

Comment: The L5-30P's that I've used are molded so the terminals can't be switched, the folded tab slides into a slot on the plug so it can't easily be switched with the other one. If you really did have to move the terminals in  correctly configured  plug to match the receptacle, that sounds like a bad idea - if the receptacle is wrong, replace it with a new one, don't make two "wrongs" by creating a bad plug to match a bad outlet.

Comment: @Xen2050 - I haven't seen a simple plug-in outlet tester that fits an L5-30 outlet, A multimeter is probably his best bet to confirm hot and neutral.

Comment: @Johnny I noticed, tried a web search for a tester that would fit a bigger locking plug, no results. But, [adapters are plentiful](http://www.amazon.com/Conntek-Locking-Adapter-Straight-Connector/dp/B001H9TSEW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q%26tag%3Dduckduckgo-d-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB001H9TSEW), and I get the feeling the OP has already made up their mind, but maybe a tester / safety device is the only thing that could convince them, if they're mistaken

Comment: Why can't you fix the outlet?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should never modify a plug by "switching terminals". So step 1: **put the plug back to the original configuration**. The problem here is seems to be in the receptacle, so **fix the receptacle**.

You didn't say what type of receptacle you have; there are three types of 30A twist-lock receptacles:

[image: L5-30R] [image: L6-30R] [image: L14-30R]

Your statement about switching the terminals "and now it fits" seems to imply though that you maybe have the wrong receptacle? If neutral/ground were swapped, it would still physically fit, it just may not actually work (though chances are most things still would work, but there are safety reasons not to have neutral and hot backwards).

There are many types of NEMA receptacles:

[image: NEMA twist-lock receptacles]

If you have the wrong one, you need to install the correct one. For the most part, there are two considerations in switching:

- The L14-* receptacles are combined 120/240V, so have 3 wires plus ground. You could cap off one and switch to a 2-wire receptacle, but you obviously can't go the other way without running a new wire.
- Moving to a same or lower-rated (amps) receptacle is okay, but moving to a higher-rated one may not be: it likely requires a larger gauge wire to be run.

If you want more assistance, tell us what actual receptacle and plug you have (take pictures, if needed), tell us the wiring is, what the circuit breaker is rated for and if it's a 1- or 2-pole, and anything else that may be relevant.